# Excel - Is there a way to sort by matching values? (Note: Sorting Doesn't Work Here)

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have a list of products with UPC codes.

I have another list of UPC codes with inventory numbers.

The inventory list is much, much larger and contains many UPC codes for which I do not have products.

I tried sorting both UPC codes and seeing if they match but that doesn't work since the inventory list has many UPC codes in between.

I was wondering if there was a way to sort by matching values. For example, if values in column A & B match, display value in column C.  That way, I could keep the order of column A and obtain the values I need in column C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question isn't that clear, but if I got it right, you need `vlookup()` here.

What I think I understood is (or something similar, do correct me if you meant otherwise):

- In one table, column A contains product names, and column B contains the products' corresponding UPC codes.
- In a second table, let's say another sheet named `Sheet2`, column A contains UPC codes with their corresponding inventory number.
- You want to get the corresponding inventory number of a certain product in the first table, with the only thing in common being the UPC code, and put this inventory number in column C of the first table.

In this situation, you will put this formula in cell C2 of the first table (assuming that the first row contains headers):

```
=VLOOKUP(B2, Sheet2!A:B, 2, 0)
```

`B2` contains the UPC code excel will look for in the second table.

`Sheet2!A:B` is the second table, with column A as the reference column (the column to look for the UPC code) and column B with the inventory number you want to obtain.

`2` is the column index. The first column, column A, has index 1, so column B has index 2.

`0` means an exact match.

Drag the formula to the bottom and this should do it. If the second table is large, it might take a while for the formula to evaluate since it has to look through a lot of values before returning the result.

Comment: Jerry, I meant that Column A would have UPC codes from a list of products I have in my database. Column B would have all UPC codes from a ton of products, some of which are products which I need inventory numbers on.  My supplier uploads an inventory xls file that inludes inventories for all products.  If I can match my products UPC codes with their UPC codes, then I will get the inventory numbers. Would your method still be able to do that?

Comment: I mean, technically they are on two separate sheets, but I copied my UPC codes over to theirs to see if I could figure out a match.  In the mean time, I will be trying your method with separate sheets.  Thank you for your response!

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah a picture or a file would really clear things up! Otherwise, it seems like you still can use vlookup. I added the extra detail just so you can tweak it a bit yourself, but remember that the UPC codes in the second table must be in the first column. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: I think your way will work. I am setting up a new sheet like you assumed with sheet 1, Column A containing Product Names, Column B containing the corresponding UPC codes.  In sheet 2, I have column A containing UPC codes and column B containing corresponding inventory numbers.  So far, I get a #N/A result for each.

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah Those indicate non-matches. Sometimes, these are due to spaces (if you can, remove all the spaces through a find/replace), or matching numbers stored as text with actual numbers or vice versa (numbers stored as text will have a little green corner at the top left and actual numbers won't).

Comment: I am reading up on the VLOOKUP function and it seems like the values I am looking for must be in the same row for there to be a match.  The problem is that I have 300 UPC codes to find inventory numbers for.  The inventory list has 10,000+ UPC codes of which I only need to match 300.  There are most likely not on the same row. Thoughts?

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah Hmm, I did a small example with random numbers see this [xlsx file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23298677/UPC%20Codes_vlookup_22_Jul_13.xlsx). Is this close to what you're trying to do?

Comment: Well I'll be damned.  This is exactly that.  Thank you very much. I hope I can figure it out from here.  I will update my question with an exact step by step process once I go through this and figure out how it works.  Thanks again!

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah Lol, okay, good luck! Sometimes, it's not the formula's fault but the data's. You just have to keep an eye for it :) If you provide a sample, I could perhaps insert in the first formulae and return it back to you. It's a bit difficult to explain how things work through a screen, but I'll try if you want me to elaborate a bit more on how vlookup works.

Comment: Hmm.. I copied the UPC codes and inventory into the corresponding columns based on your sheet, and can't seem to get it to work. Would you be able to take a look at it? The file can be viewed here:  https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6AU0KmlV4F5aXZZVFZCRHpxOE0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Okay, figured it out. First I set the values to "TRUE" and for some reason, I have the enter the ' character before all my UPC codes.

Comment: See this question if you have any ideas on why this method works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17777394/why-does-this-work-exploring-the-vlookup-formula

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah See my second comment on this answer which basically points to what your problem was. If I had a picture, I'd have quickly spotted it through either left alignment of numbers or the little green cornered cell. As I told you, vlookup works as long as the format you're looking for and the reference are both the same. There are various tricks to bypass them, but each have their own way of being applied!

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah Also, the google spreadsheet is not shared!