# Why does this work? Exploring the VLOOKUP formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have an excel 2010 spreadsheet with 4 columns.

Column A:  A list of UPC codes for products I sell.  Around 300 lines.

Column B:  Formula (more on this later)

Column C:  Another list of UPC codes. These UPC codes are around 10,000 lines.

Column D:  An inventory count which corresponds to UPC codes in Column C.

The formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,C:D,2,FALSE)
```

The idea is to match up my UPC codes with my supplier's UPC codes to retrieve the corresponding inventory count.

All data was pasted into a new spreadsheet from other spreadsheets and were pasted as **values only** to ensure no other characters or formatting was imported.

This formula was dragged down for all 300 lines.

I received the error #N/A in Column B until I inserted the following character before the values in Column A:

```
'
```

Note: the `'` was inserted manually by clicking on the cell and typing `'` in the box above.

Immediately after this was done, the #N/A would change to the corresponding inventory retrieved from Column D.

My question is why does this work?  Why does the method without the `'` not work?  Is there a way to quickly add the `'` before all values in Column A?  Note: CONCATENATE("'",A2) does not work for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

raphael you've got it there - your number is stored as text in one of the lookup tables, and as a number in the other. Adding a ' to each line will fix it, but it's pretty horrible task. Clicking the green arrow can also fix it, but excels default method can be really slow for big tables (And it also changes your source data, which for me is a no-no, as when you update the data, you'll have to do it again). Changing the formatting rarely helps in this situation.

If the table contains numbers and lookup value is number-stored-as-text, you can multiply the lookup value by 1:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2*1,C:D,2,FALSE)
```

If the table contains "text" and lookup value is number, you can convert it to text like this:

```
=VLOOKUP(TEXT(A1,0),C:D,2,FALSE)
```

Comment: +1 for the string/number explanation, -1 for the unhelpful "trick" in the situation described in question - lookup value is already a number, 1st column of table array are strings

Comment: deathApril, fair point, I had the text/number the wrong way around. It's possible to flip it the other way, but it requires an array formula (ctrl+shift+enter after completing) {=VLOOKUP(A2,C:D*1,2,false)} the concept is the same. I'm happy to be updated if there's another way of doing this without adding to the source data

Answer (score 0):

Here's my theory.  In VLOOKUP, if the lookup value (A2) is smaller than the smallest value in the looked-up table (C:D) then it returns N/A.  When you prepend the quote sign (') you make A2 a string, not a number.  So for example a UPC of 1002 is no longer treated as the number one-thousand-and-two but as the string sequence one-zero-zero-two.  That lets VLOOKUP do the comparison differently and avoid the N/A.

You might try Ctrl-1 in column A and get it to treat them all as text.

Comment: A valid theory. However, it does not work.  And a counter argument would be, if that theory is correct, why does the =CONCATENATE(E2,A2) not work where the A column is the UPC code and the E column is the `'`. The concatenated result is the exact same output, but it does not work with the VLOOKUP when this new column is pasted in column A.  My guess is that is because the actual value of the A column has to include the `'` whereas the concatenated result does not have this `'` inside the cell's value when you click on it. Tt shows only the UPC code displayed without `'` in cell's value.

Comment: Actually, I am going to give this credit since after playing with it further, I noticed that when I changed the format (i.e. to text or a general number) I received an icon to the left of the column. The error reported that the number was stored as text. I had some options, one of which was to convert to a number. After that, it works liked a charm.  Thank you for helping me solve this problem!

Comment: this theory is bogus - see [documentation](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/vlookup-function-HP010343011.aspx) or even default help text in Excel itself - if the last argument is `FALSE`, only exact matches will be found, if `TRUE`, then data need to be sorted (A->Z),, for TRUE + unsorted data, the behaviour of VLOOKUP is completely useless